# What is the advantage of creating new services in AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

When using AngularJS, why would it be beneficial to make a new service rather than just sticking with $http?

Why would I do something like this:

```
app.factory('forecast', ['$http', function($http) { 
    return $http.get('https://s3.amazonaws.com/codecademy-content/courses/ltp4/forecast-api/forecast.json')
        .success(function(data) { 
          return data; 
        }) 
        .error(function(err) { 
          return err; 
        }); 
}]);



app.controller('MainController', ['$scope', 'forecast', function($scope, forecast) {
    forecast.success(function(data) {
        $scope.fiveDay = data;
    });
}]);
```

When I could just stick with this:

```
app.controller('MainController', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http) {

    $http.get('https://s3.amazonaws.com/codecademy-content/courses/ltp4/forecast-api/forecast.json') 
        .success(function(data) { 
          $scope.fiveDay = data;
        }) 
        .error(function(err) { 
          return err; 
        }); 
}]);
```

Maybe in this instance it doesn't matter, but since you can make new services in AngularJS I assume there are some instances when it is beneficial. Thanks in advance!

Comment: In this case it's useless (except the url is private), but you could do a lot more with a custom service: chain multiple http calls, process the data returned by the promise `return success(function(data) { return processData(data); })`, keep private variables, expose a public api, etc

Comment: It also helps with unit testing components in isolation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What happens if you now need a new controller called WeatherController that wants access to the same type of weather data as MainController.  Without the forecast service, you'd have to cut and paste and repeat the $http.get.

Which is fine if it's just limited to two instances I guess.  But then what happens if the forecast-api URL changes?  Now you have to change it in 2 locations.

What if you want a 10day forecast instead?

The point of a service, or any modular code, is to help separate discrete chunks of code into modules that can be reused wherever they are needed.  And then you only have to worry about one place to fix or alter the service.

It's sometimes a bit hard to see that when you only need it in one place, but when writing code, you have to think a few iterations ahead to try to foresee some other reasonable use cases to make life easier down the road.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to all the answers that people will write in here.

The main idea is to not repeat your code and divide your code into modules.
Assume that you have another controller that use the same *$http* resource.
So you have to copy and paste the code to the new controller instead of elegant call to the service and use his methods.

**What about handle you code?**

You are working on big project and you have a lot of references to *$http* requests from thousand controllers, BUT you moved your site to a new domain, or you server developer changed the API to use other method.
Well, You have to look for all the conrtollers that used that URL.
BUT if you would use a service you could change it in one place only.

There are more benefits, But not for your example.